# SQL Converting column's recorded seconds to hours:minutes:seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a table (Main), which records number of seconds worked in a day for a list of people. I'm trying to convert these seconds into hh:mm:ss.

trying to use:

```
DECLARE @TimeinSecond INT
SET @TimeinSecond = main.column -- Change the seconds

SELECT RIGHT('0' + CAST(@TimeinSecond / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CAST((@TimeinSecond / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CAST(@TimeinSecond % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)
```

main.column wont register as what needs to be converted here. Can a column be selected for full time conversion? (The seconds worked daily are different for everyone)

Comment: What do you expect "main.column" to do? This isn't how you retrieve data from a table in SQL...

Comment: Andy answered me, I appreciate your response. I think I just over thought this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignment of column to the variable has no sense in sql server (I'm supposing you're using it since you've tagged your question with `ssms`).

It looks like you need just select this column value and make some calculations over it

```
select 
    RIGHT('0' + CAST(column / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
    RIGHT('0' + CAST((column / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
    RIGHT('0' + CAST(column % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)
from main
```

Comment: Yessir, thank you I've been looking at this code too long probably... that was stupid simple, thanks much! I will mark it answered in 6 mins when I'm allowed to.

Answer (score 3):

```
select * , convert(varchar(20), dateadd(ss, secondsColumn, 0), 108) from main
```

Output
**09:20:34**

Answer (score 0):

You can get date from seconds with query below. Simply add quantity of seconds to your date and then convert value to varchar for format like `'hh:mm:ss'`

```
    ;WITH test_data AS(
    SELECT N'20160113' AS working_date, 3600 AS SECONDS
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N'20160113', 2400
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N'20160113', 1500
    )

SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(ss, [seconds], working_date), 114), 8) FROM test_data
```

Comment: He isn't asking for a date, he's asking for a length of time.